# Data point missing/overlapping in geom_point ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have around 900 data point in my dataset, but after I plot, the data plot in the plot looks like less than 100, is that because of overlapping? or some other reason, I am not sure.

This is my plot:

[image: Plot/data point seems less than hunder]

my code

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.numeric(`x1`), y=`x2`, color=`x3`)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,135,15))
```

Comment: Should I use position = "dodge"?

Comment: Thoughts: (1) use a less-opaque color, adding the alpha channel (e.g., `#ff0000` "red" at 50% transparency is `#ff000080` or `scales::alpha("red",0.5)`); (2) use `jitter` to jitter the data around (in either or both directions).

Comment: Is that because of overlapping?

Comment: Without seeing your dataset, it's hard to say if you have overlapping.  Some key things to consider would be to use `jitter` as mentioned, or set your points to use alpha of 0.5 or lower.  Overplotting will then show you "darker" colored points to be where overlapping occurs.  Another way to judge if something is not being plotted in your dataset is that when you initiate the plot command, do you get any warnings posted?  If there were some points elimated from the plot you would see something like `X rows removed...` (forget the exact message).

Answer (score 1):

Two techniques to deal with overlapping/coincident data:

1. Jitter the points so that most overlapping points shift a little;
2. Apply alpha to the color so that darker points indicate more-frequent data.

### Data

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = round(rnorm(100), 0),
  y = round(rnorm(100), 0)
)
head(dat)
#    x  y
# 1  1  1
# 2 -1  1
# 3  0 -1
# 4  1  2
# 5  0 -1
# 6  0  0

xtabs(~ x + y, data=dat)
#     y
# x    -2 -1  0  1  2  3
#   -3  0  1  0  0  0  1
#   -2  1  3  1  0  0  0
#   -1  1  1 11  7  1  0
#   0   1 13 13  8  1  0
#   1   2  6 17  4  1  0
#   2   0  0  5  1  0  0
```

### The problem

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot problem overlaps]

### Transparency (alpha)

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(color = "#00000022")
```

[image: ggplot with alpha]

### Jittering

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_jitter()
```

[image: ggplot, too much jitter]

That might be too much, so we can adjust how much things shift around.

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1)
```

[image: ggplot, less jitter]

### Both alpha and jitter

Not strictly required here, but it might be useful to do *both*:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(color = "#00000022") +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1)
```

[image: ggplot, both jitter and alpha]